# Xamarin Studio cannot find an assembly which is not existing and throws compile error "Error executing task ResolveAssemblyRefernce"

Tags: macos, mono, xamarin-studio, resolveassemblyreference

I'm getting the following error when I try to compile my project:

> Error executing task ResolveAssemblyReference: Could not load file or assembly '//DataLayer/bin/Debug/EntityFramework.Extended.dll' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified. (DataLayer)

I used to use this dependency, together with EntityFramework, that is true, but I removed both of it. This all happened via nuget. A check on the project with grep:

```
grep -r -i EntityFramework *
```

reveals that the string only exists in two files inside comments, nothing else, so why am I getting this exception?

I feel the easiest thing to do right now is to start a new project and configure it properly without EntityFramework.Extended from the beginning, but I still would like to have an answer, in case I encounter similar problems in the future.

A small remark - I use Xamarin studio in OS X to develop a .Net web application in mono. I have the latest version, Xamarin Studio 5.2 with Mono 3.4 and am compiling the project by using .Net 4.0 profile.

Comment: Are you using NuGet to install EntityFramework?

Comment: Yes I used it, but it's uninstalled as well